# SDK access to DJI's TakeOffWidget

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Are there SDK API calls that have access to the UXSDK class TakeOffWidget? What I would like to do is get its state and modify its take-off height (or the take-off/hover height for the quad in general). If not the TakeOffWidget, would there be other calls that can control the hover height (with or without GPS access)?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There is not.  What I did was to create my own class and extend the widget.  I did this so I could support metric and imperial display but the same should be possible in your case.

Note: takeoff height is not part of the widget; takeoff height is firmware defined using the takeoff SDK call.

I am unaware of any call that you can use to change the takeoff height.